# How to give javascript sessionStorage new name with loop

Tags: javascript, loops, key, session-storage

I am trying to make a button, which creates some data and saves it in the sessionStorage. I want to give every data a key number from 0 and up. The first time the button is pressed it gets the name/key 0. If the button is then pressed again the name for the new data string/object would be 1 and so on. The thing is that I dont want to overwrite existing data in sessionStorage, so it should check if there is a string/object in the sessionStorage; if yes give it a new name, if no save it.

In my following code, cpData is the data I want to store in sessionStorage:

```
    for (var index = 0; index <= window.sessionStorage.key(index); index++) {
        if (index > window.sessionStorage.key(index)) {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(index, cpData);
            break;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by myself. This code should do it if one is needs the to do the same:

```
for (var index = 0; index >= window.sessionStorage.key(index); index++) {
        if (window.sessionStorage.key(index) === null) {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(index, JSON.stringify(cpData));
            break;
        } else if (index > window.sessionStorage.key(index)) {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem(index, JSON.stringify(cpData));
            break;
        }
    };
```

This time it checks wether or not `window.sessionStorage.key(index)` isn't there. If so it will create a datastring. The `break;` statement stops the loop immediately. Now the next time the button is pressed and the loop is started, it can see that there is already a datastring, it will then continue to loop until `index` value is bigger than the key biggest key value at the moment. When it is bigger than al previous saved data, it will save the data and `break;` the loop.

If one wants to check it by him/herself add this to the same script:

```
var i = 0, oJson = {}, sKey;
    for (i; sKey = window.sessionStorage.key(i); i++) {
        oJson[sKey] = window.sessionStorage.getItem(sKey);

    }
    console.log(oJson);
```

This will print out ALL sessionStorage data in console.